# Having a CORS issue with my full stack app

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, flask

[image: CORS]

I am trying to access the site from my guest VM to my host machine but having CORS issues as you can see above.

[image: Network Error]

Getting a Network Error from my flask backend.  I added the flask_cors library to handle CORS.

```
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

On my front end I added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' to the header for the axios post request:

```
 var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        }
```

Comment: You'll want to set CORS-related options on the back end, these are in turn evaluated by the browser (which is now throwing the `same origin policy disallows reading the remote resource [...]`) error

Comment: I thought this would do that?  https://enable-cors.org/server_flask.html

Comment: You are right, I must have skipped the `CORS(app)` part. That being said, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'` on the front end is unnecessary. That exact header is what you should see in the _response_ from the back end. You can either see what the server is responding with in the `network` tab in the `dev tools` of your browser or send a POST _request_ to `http://localhost:5000/convert` using `curl` or something similar and check the response header

Comment: Okay, but the response is unfortunately a 500.  Network Error as shown above.  Front end in the console log is still saying that CORS is blocked.

Comment: If you get a `500 Internal Server Error` then the problem is with the back end you're trying to connect to. That would explained why the  `CORS(app)` isn't working as expected. Check the logs on the VM